# Agrupar consulta por mes

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta en mysql para calcular la rentabilidad, la cual me la agrupa por día, no he logrado agruparla por mes. Agradecería mucho de su ayuda. La idea es que me muestre la rentabilidad por mes. Anexo dos códigos, el que funciona perfecto por día y el que quisiera me agrupe por mes. No me muestra error, sencillamente no me agrupa. Me trae los resultados por días. Agradeceria me dijeran donde estoy agrupando mal, o como podría agrupar por mes la consulta.

```
SELECT fechas.fecha , 
        ies.ingresos , 
        ies.egresos , 
        ies.socios , 
        ord.totalorden ,
        cot.totalcotizacion,
        ies.activos,
        ies.rentabilidad

      FROM ( SELECT @fe := @fe+interval 1 day fecha
               FROM registros, cotizaciones, ordenes
                  , ( SELECT @fe := '2020-03-20'- interval 1 day ) v
               LIMIT 7
           ) fechas
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT r.fecregistro
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS socios 
                         ,SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 13,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS activos
                         ,(1-((SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,0))-SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 13,r.vlrregistro,0)))/SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,0))))*100 AS rentabilidad
                    FROM registros AS r 
                      WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) 
                        AND r.idestado <> 7 
                    GROUP BY r.fecregistro
                  ) ies
           ON ies.fecregistro = fechas.fecha
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop) AS fecorden
                         , SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden 
                      FROM ordenes 
                      WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                      GROUP BY fecorden 
                  ) ord
          ON ord.fecorden = fechas.fecha
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT feccotizacion
                         , SUM(totalcotizacion) totalcotizacion
                      FROM cotizaciones 
                      WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                      GROUP BY feccotizacion
                  ) cot
         ON cot.feccotizacion = fechas.fecha         
      ORDER BY fechas.fecha asc
```

Pensé que funcionaría de esta manera pero no lo agrupa.

```
SELECT fechas.fecha , 
        ies.ingresos , 
        ies.egresos , 
        ies.socios , 
        ord.totalorden ,
        cot.totalcotizacion,
        ies.activos,
        ies.rentabilidad

      FROM ( SELECT @fe := @fe+interval 1 day fecha
               FROM registros, cotizaciones, ordenes
                  , ( SELECT @fe := '2020-03-20'- interval 1 day ) v
               LIMIT 7
           ) fechas
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT r.fecregistro
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos
                         , SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS socios 
                         ,SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 13,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS activos
                         ,(1-((SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,0))-SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria = 13,r.vlrregistro,0)))/SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,0))))*100 AS rentabilidad
                    FROM registros AS r 
                      WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) 
                        AND r.idestado <> 7 
                    GROUP BY MONTH(r.fecregistro)
                  ) ies
           ON ies.fecregistro = fechas.fecha
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop) AS fecorden
                         , SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden 
                      FROM ordenes 
                      WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                      GROUP BY MONTH(fecorden) 
                  ) ord
          ON ord.fecorden = fechas.fecha
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT feccotizacion
                         , SUM(totalcotizacion) totalcotizacion
                      FROM cotizaciones 
                      WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                      GROUP BY feccotizacion
                  ) cot
         ON cot.feccotizacion = fechas.fecha         
      ORDER BY MONTH(fechas.fecha) asc
```

[image: Esta es el resultado agrupado por día]

[image: Y quisiera algo mas o menos así pero con la consulta que tengo al principio]

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya lo tienes por días, tan solo reagrúpalo por año y mes:

```
SELECT year(d.fecha) anio
     , month(d.fecha) mes
     , sum(d.ingresos)
     , sum(d.egresos)
     , sum(d.socios)
     , sum(d.activos)
     , sum(d.rentabilidad)
  FROM ( <TU CONSULTA ACTUAL>
       ) d
  GROUP BY anio, mes
```

Comment: @ Sal gracias por comentar amigo. No sé si no lo supe hacer pero me da error de sintaxis. Sería tan amable de indicarme con más detalles si debo incluir desde el from o toda la consulta completa.. gracias.

Comment: ya me funcionó amigo. Sin embargo si los meses vienen desde el año anterior me muestra los meses 11, 12, 3,2,1 en vez de ordenarlos por 11,12,1,2,3.  Agradecería mucho cómo podría darle un ORDER por mes y año para que halla claridad. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El ordenamiento predeterminado es ascendente según GROUP BY, si necesitas modificarlo agrega el ORDER BY a tu conveniencia, ya sea ASC o DESC.

Comment: ya quedó listo amigo. Era agregar un GROUP BY ano, mes y un ORDER BY ano, mes. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un problema similar al que me enfrente hace unos meses lo resolvi de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT 
id as bid,
nombre,
monto,
numero_de_envios,
cantidad_mensual,
monto_maximo,monto_total,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=1,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as enero,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=2,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as febrero,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=3,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as marzo,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=4,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as abril,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=5,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as mayo,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=6,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as junio,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=7,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as julio,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=8,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as agosto,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=9,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as septiembre,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=10,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as octubre,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=11,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as noviembre,
    (select SUM(IF(month(fecha_de_proceso)=12,monto,0)) from RiesgosEnviosBenef where bid=id group by id) as diciembre
   FROM RiesgosEnviosBenef   
   group by id;
```

Realice un select para cada mes haciendo las operaciones necesarias dentro del mes en cuestión

Comment: Tu GROUP by externo no debería agrupar por todas las columnas del Select principal?

Comment: Si en efecto, para este caso el id es un número único que pertenece a un beneficiario(Cliente) y de esa forma conseguí hacer la sumatoria de cada pago mensual por un beneficiario único en la tabla